# PHP Select from drop-down

Tags: javascript, php

I can't select the top option from the drop-down only the options under the top.

```html
<form>
    <select name="car_license" class="form-control" id="car_license" onchange="change()">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) { ?>
            <option value="<? echo $data[$i]['license'] ?>"><? echo $data[$i]['license'] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
</form>
    
<script>
    function change(){
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
</script>

$license = $_POST['car_license'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't select"? Is it disabled somehow? Or maybe your JS function doesn't run when you select the top option?

Comment: Can you please show the content of `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem not complete but  will suggest you try this.

```
 <form method="post">
   <select name="car_license" class="form-control" id="car_license" 
    onchange="change()">
   <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    ?>
    <option value="<? echo $data[$i]['license'] ?>"><? echo $data[$i] 
     ['license'] ?></option>
  <? } ?>
   </select>
</form>

   <script>
       function change(){
       //use ajax to submit using "post" method
       }
  </script>
```